# Pull whole array values (clone copy of the array) using iterator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some iterator that pulls a value from an array.

There is a sequence

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

which can be accessed by an iterator `it.next()`

I want to pull whole value of the sequence using the iterator.

Perhaps, the half-way code would be

```
var seq =[];
var i = 0;

 while (some_condition) 
      {          
        seq[i] = it.next();
        i++;
      }
```

I usually use

`if (!foo) bar;`

to check the value existence, but in this case, it does not work.

What is the smartest pattern to implement this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Maybe you could show your implementation of the Iterator?

Comment: Could you please explain "*in this case, it does not work.*?" What about it doesn't work? What happens? What did you expect to happen? What is the `some_condition` you're currently trying?

Comment: The iterator behaves in very common way like JS1.7 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: Well, like I said: I want to pull/clone whole value of the sequence `[0,1,2,3,4]` using the iterator `it.next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another more more java like solution which should work with all versions of javascript:

```
function fakeIterator(array){

    var i = 0;
    return {
        next: function(){
            i += 1;
            return array[i - 1];
        },
        hasNext: function(){
            return i < array.length;
        }
    };
}
```

Then this should work:

```
var myIterator = fakeIterator([0, 4, 6]);
while(myIterator.hasNext()){
    console.log('presenting: ' + myIterator.next());
}

//  =>
//      presenting: 0
//      presenting: 4
//      presenting: 6
```

Comment: I'm really sorry I would like to accept your solution either, if possible. I like this hasNext() method, and will implement to mine.

Comment: Both solutions work, but @tg435's solution has the advantage of being compatible with the current ES6 draft gennerator/iterator specification, meaning when/if you decide to switch to a native implementation you will probably have to edit less code.

Comment: Right, actually, I think ES6 also can employ this hasNext method, very concise. Anyway really works well for my project, so accepted Thanks!

Comment: My solution works in ES6, but it does not match the ES6 gennerator specification. This is probably of little importance though. In any case, I am glad I could help. :D

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) with generators:

```
 for(var x of it)
    seq.push(x)
```

If you want to use `next`, check the `done` property:

```
while(1) {
    x = it.next()
    if(x.done)
        break
    seq.push(x.value)
}
```

If you implement your own iterator, I'd recommend to keep up with standards and use the [harmony protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol), for example:

```
function rangeIter(min, max) {
    var done = false;
    return {
        next: function() {
            if(done)
                throw Error('Generator has already finished');
            var value;
            if(min >= max) {
                done = true;
                value = undefined;
            } else {
                value = min++;
            }
            return {done:done, value:value};
        }
    }
}
```

This code behaves just like a "real" iterator would:

```
it = rangeIter(3, 7)

console.log(it.next())  // { done: false, value: 3 }
console.log(it.next())  // { done: false, value: 4 }
console.log(it.next())  // { done: false, value: 5 }
console.log(it.next())  // { done: false, value: 6 }
console.log(it.next())  // { done: true, value: undefined }
console.log(it.next())  // Error: Generator has already finished
```

Comment: This requires node 0.11 or greater using the --harmony flag.

Comment: Thanks,and sorry, actually, I implemented in node.js and the iterator does not have such a functionality.  Perhaps I need to implement something for it. I still need another answer..

Comment: I mean, the whole iterator stuff is implemented by myself. I simply illustrated ES7 for the basic concept of the iterator.

Comment: @KenOKABE: you still can implement the harmony protocol (return `{value:.., done:..}` from `next`.

Comment: @KenOKABE: I've added an example

Comment: Versatile solution. Looks great and accepted as the answer. Appreciated thg435

Comment: I am sorry, I definitely use your code, but for the question in this case, `hasNext` method is very adequate for my current need , so I accepted his GR's answer.

Comment: @KenOKABE: nothing to feel sorry about. You accept what works for you the best, that's the point. Good luck with your project!